# Magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.1 upgrade issue

Tags: error, magento2.3, magento-upgrade

I have upgraded Magento from 2.2.5 to 2.3.1 using composer. Everything downloaded. While running `setup: upgrade`, I got an error like below,

I checked with the previous version there is decimal version changed in 2.3.x. Any idea why this error?

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`vv`.`#sql-4a2b_1b18`, CONSTRAINT
>   `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`)
>   REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE), query was: ALTER
>   TABLE `quote_item` MODIFY COLUMN `discount_amount` decimal(20, 4) 
>   NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Discount Amount", MODIFY COLUMN
>   `base_discount_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Base
>   Discount Amount", MODIFY COLUMN `tax_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL
>   DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Tax Amount", MODIFY COLUMN `base_tax_amount`
>   decimal(20, 4)  NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Base Tax Amount", MODIFY
>   COLUMN `row_total` decimal(20, 4)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Row
>   Total", MODIFY COLUMN `base_row_total` decimal(20, 4)  NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Base Row Total", MODIFY COLUMN
>   `row_total_with_discount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT "Row
>   Total With Discount", MODIFY COLUMN `base_tax_before_discount`
>   decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Base Tax Before Discount", MODIFY
>   COLUMN `tax_before_discount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Tax Before
>   Discount", MODIFY COLUMN `price_incl_tax` decimal(20, 4)  NULL 
>   COMMENT "Price Incl Tax", MODIFY COLUMN `base_price_incl_tax`
>   decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Base Price Incl Tax", MODIFY COLUMN
>   `row_total_incl_tax` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT "Row Total Incl
>   Tax", MODIFY COLUMN `base_row_total_incl_tax` decimal(20, 4)  NULL 
>   COMMENT "Base Row Total Incl Tax", MODIFY COLUMN
>   `discount_tax_compensation_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT
>   "Discount Tax Compensation Amount", MODIFY COLUMN
>   `base_discount_tax_compensation_amount` decimal(20, 4)  NULL  COMMENT
>   "Base Discount Tax Compensation Amount", ADD CONSTRAINT
>   `QUOTE_ITEM_PARENT_ITEM_ID_QUOTE_ITEM_ITEM_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`parent_item_id`) REFERENCES `quote_item` (`item_id`)  ON DELETE
>   CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE,
>   ADD CONSTRAINT `QUOTE_ITEM_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`)  ON DELETE SET NULL

Answer (score 0):

just doing one thing you can divide query in 2 parts and execute. first Alter Table query and the second is apply foreign key manual so it's working